# Where to get the Deployer Extension Jar files

Tags: deployer-extension

I started working on Custom Deployer Extension. I am referring from the "[Create a module](http://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-894AB0F0-313C-45A3-B8FC-8A02DA894C93)" topic in the SDL Web 8 documentation.

But I am unable to find the following JAR file.

**com.perfectsoftware.AppServer.***

help me on where we can get this JAR file.

Comment: That's a sample package name. It's suppose to be a reference to "insert your own custom code". It's also been in our manuals for a very long time it seems: http://media.leidenuniv.nl/legacy/ContentDeliveryReferenceGuide_51SP4.pdf

Answer (score 5):

The documentation contains example code and the developer who wrote it was probabaly trying to be funny by including an import to an imaginary Java package:

```
 import com.perfectsoftware.AppServer.*;
```

The line is just there to indicate that you can also import any third party package you might need in your custom Content Deployer Modules. The code is purely example code, as is this line:

```
//imaginary appserver API
AppManager server = CachingAppServer.getManagerInstance();
```

So there is no way you can actually compile this code, it is purely there to indicate how you can write a custom Content Deployer Module.

Comment: +1 and thanks for leaving a comment on the SDL Docs topic. Btw, when did you get a user-specific Doc login? :-O

Comment: @AlvinReyes just logged in as guest, but you can change your name on every comment, I can use your name next time ;o)